# Email template with formula field not showing properly

Tags: email-template, formula-field, salesforce-id

I have created a formula field "Assess" formula defined is:

```
IF(
    OR(ISNULL(Assessment__c), ISBLANK(Assessment__c)),
    HYPERLINK('/apex/avNewAssessmentDGView?assessmentResultId='+Id+'&isRiskCentricAssessment=true&retURL=/'+Assessment_Issue__c, 'Assess' , 'self'),
    HYPERLINK('/apex/avNewAssessmentDGView?assessmentResultId='+Id+'&From=GapAnalysis&assessmentResponderId='+Assessment_Responder__c +'&retURL=/'+ Assessment_Issue__c , 'Assess', 'self')
)
```

This field is referred email template(HTML) which is coming with [\prepared link]

I recieved following mail:

> **The user c2 has submitted the responses for the controls assigned to him. Please
>   click[/apex/avNewAssessmentDGView?assessmentResultId=a0F1500000Hs7pz&isRiskCentricAssessment=true&retURL=/a061500000c3s3l]Assessto
>   perform the necessary action.**

Comment: Use double quotes when wrapping your hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Use Double Quotes within your Hyperlink.

Salesforce believes you wish to use static text, hence the display of your link in an incorrect format.

Below should resolve your issue.

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISNULL(Assessment__c),
        ISBLANK(Assessment__c)
    ),
    HYPERLINK("/apex/avNewAssessmentDGView?assessmentResultId=" + Id + "&isRiskCentricAssessment=true&retURL=/" + Assessment_Issue__c, "Assess" , "self"),
    HYPERLINK("/apex/avNewAssessmentDGView?assessmentResultId=" + Id + "&From=GapAnalysis&assessmentResponderId=" + Assessment_Responder__c + "&retURL=/" + Assessment_Issue__c , "Assess" , "self")
)
```